# How do I fix a "Prefs file removed in background /home/steven/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml" error?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, preferences

I've been programming on Windows for the majority of my program with no problems with preferences. I just booted up Ubuntu 12.04 and loaded up my classes into Eclipse. At run time, I receive this in the console:

```
Oct 12, 2012 8:14:38 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$6 run
WARNING: Prefs file removed in background /home/steven/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml
```

I understand this has something to do with the `preferences` system on Ubuntu but several `Google` searches resulted in no solutions. Could anyone help me on how do I fix such an error?

Comment: Some ubuntu tools like `BleachBit` `Ubuntu Tweak` etc., delete this file. Remove those tools and reinstall JVM.

Comment: I would have better posted it at `askubuntu.com` or `unix.stackexchange.com`

Comment: I don't have either of those listed. I will re-install and report back results. Thanks.

Comment: I re-installed; no dice.

Comment: The preferences implementation in the JVM is system dependant; are you calling resetPreferences(...) somewhere? That would most probably emit that warning (it is not an error).

Comment: No, reset preferences is not used anywhere in my program.

Comment: Exact same problem here with so many hours of googling to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are affected by this bug:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068373

> (prefs) FileSystemPreferences writes \0 to XML storage, causing loss
> of all preferences
>
> If you call `prefs.put(key, "some string with \0 in it")` ...
>
> The XML writer happily writes the `\0` into the file. I think it escapes
> it, but as already mentioned, this is pointless. Then later, when you
> try to read it back in, the XML file is invalid. You get a warning on
> the logs about the preferences file being invalid and all your
> preferences are wiped.
>
> ADDITIONAL OS VERSION INFORMATION:
>
> Occurs on all
> flavours of Linux we have tested. Issue is also reproducible on any
> platform if you deliberately use this PreferencesFactory.
>
> You also get the following output on stderr:

> ```
> Dec 29, 2014 9:19:19 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$6 run 
> WARNING: Invalid preferences format in /Users/daniel/.java/.userPrefs/com/acme/testing/prefs.xml 
> Dec 29, 2014 9:19:19 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$6 run 
> WARNING: Prefs file removed in background /Users/daniel/.java/.userPrefs/com/acme/testing/prefs.xml
> ```

**Solution:** update to Java 9+

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question? or a simple comment?

Comment: I have the same issue :( did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

As [user11153](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1795426/user11153) wrote originally this seems to be related to the null character `\0` (or some other unicode experiments I did recently... ). This happens for me with JShell 17.0.1 installed with the jdk that is built and deployed by the IntelliJ IDEA.

I experimented a little with the file that is saved in your home directory (for me in `.java/.userPrefs/tool/JShell/IncorrectFormatPrefs.xml`, but this should be similar in your case) until I found the offending line

```xml
<entry key="HISTORY_LINE_161" value="&quot;<ffff>&quot;.length()"/>
```

After I removed this line and renamed the file from `IncorrectFormatPrefs.xml` to `prefs.xml` the warning vanished.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem when running intellij idea in ubuntu 20.04.

First, I have inttelij in /opt directory then error happen when trying to start. "Pref file removed..."

Put inttelij in home directory and problem solved.